# Let $a,b,c$ be integers, and suppose the equation.......... $\left(\frac{1}{q^2}\le \left|f\left(u\right)\right|\le K\left|u-r\right|\right)$........?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, polynomials, quadratics

**Let $a,b,c$ be integers, and suppose the equation
$$f(x)=ax^2+bx+c=0$$
has an irrational root $r$. Let $u=p/q$ be any rational number such that $|u-r|<1$. Prove that
$$\left(\frac{1}{q^2}\le \left|f\left(u\right)\right|\le K\left|u-r\right|\right)$$
for some constant $K$. Deduce that there is a constant $M$ such that
$$\left| r\frac{p}{q}\right|\ge\frac{M}{q^2}$$**

---

**My work**: Let the other root of $f(x)$ be $s$
$|f(u)|=|u-r||u-s|$

*For the upper limit of $f(u)$,*
$r-1<u<1+r$, value of $u$ is dependent on the value of $r$. We assume that that the value of $r$ and $s$ is finite so value of $|u-s|$ must also be finite.
There must exist some $K$ such that $|u-s|<K$. Multiplying $|u-r|$ we get the desired inequality.

*Another way might be:*
Let $f(u)=(u-r)(u-s)=k$ (we know $k$ is finite because $f(x)$ is defined for every $x\in \mathbb{R}$, $u-s=\frac{k}{u-r}$ which should be finite. But for $u=r$ $u-r=k=0$, $u-s$ can take any real value which takes us back to square one.
Now, $r+s=-\frac{b}{a}$ which is an integer. $s=-\frac{b}{a}-r$ (By vieta's)
Applying it to the inequality,  $u-s=u-\frac{b}{a}-r$ and we know $1<u-r<1$. $$-1-\frac{b}{a}<u-s<1-\frac{b}{a}$$ which is finite so there exists a constant $K$ such that $|u-s|<K$

*For the lower limit of $f(u)$,* we need to prove $$\frac{1}{q^2}\le \left|\frac{(p-qr)(p-qs)}{q^2} \right|$$
$$\Rightarrow 1 \le|(p-qr)(p-qs)|$$

---

Will someone proof-read my proof and provide me hints to move forward?

Comment: Try to show more directly that $|u-s|<K$ for any $u$ that satisfies $|u-r|<1$. For example, can you use the inequalities you expanded relating $u$ and $r$ to create a system of inequalities showing $-K<u-s<K$ for some $K$? (this can be done using substitution, appropriately.) Have you learned about the triangle inequality? It is not necessary for this problem, but if you are aware of it, it will help.

Comment: @c_gnar  Here's what I came up with - Let $f(u)=(u-r)(u-s)=k$ (we know $k$ is finite because f(x) is defined for every $x\in \mathbb{R} \qquad u-s=f\frac{k}{u-r}$ which should be finite. But or $u=r$ $u-r=k=0$, $u-s$ can take any real value which takes us back to square one. Now, $r+s=-\frac{b}{a}$ which is an integer. $s=-\frac{b}{a}-r$ applying it to the inequality, $u-s=u-\frac{b}{a}-r$ and we know $1<u-r<1$. So $-1-\frac{b}{a}<u-s<1-\frac{b}{a}$ which is finite so there exists a constant $K$ such that $|u-s|<K$. I'm adding it to the post to make look neater.